# Sounds that animals make

Tags: word-meaning, word-request

Example for dog:

A dog says "bow-wow".

- The dog is barking.

A cow says "moo".

- The cow is doing what? Mooing?

What are the other sounds for: a sheep, a rooster, a frog, a horse and e.t.c
Where can I find these words?

Comment: An extensive list of animal sounds can be found here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_animal_sounds

Comment: *To moo* can be used as a verb, yes, although we also say that the cow is [lowing](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/lowing).

Comment: @stangdon - That's true, but what does the fox say?

Comment: @J.R. -  http://www.popsci.com/science/article/2013-09/what-sound-does-fox-make

Comment: @J.R. Wow, amazing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***[Moo](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/moo)***:

> - the sound that a cow makes.
> - (To moo) verb.

Cambridge Dictionary

***[List of animal sounds](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_animal_sounds)***

***[To bleat](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bleat):***

> - When a sheep or goat bleats, it makes the typical sound of these animals.

***[Neigh](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/neigh?q=neigh%20)***:

> - a long, loud, high call that is produced by a horse when it is excited or frightened